# Rails редактирование с помощью Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица в которой выводятся все **tasks**, подскажите как при помощи Ajax редактировать запись какой-то конкретной строки из данной таблицы?

**Partial View** *tasks/_task.html.erb* :

```
<tr id="row_<%= task.id %>">
  <td><%= check_box_tag(:task) %></td>
  <td style="width: 90%"><%= task.name %> </td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>'.html_safe, edit_task_path(task), remote: true,
                  class: 'btn btn-warning btn-xs' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'.html_safe, task_path(task), remote: true,
                  class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
                  method: :delete,
                  data: {confirm: 'Вы уверены?'} %></td>
</tr>
```

**View** *tasks/index.hrml.erb* :

```
<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <h1>TASK#PAGE</h1>

  <%= form_for(@task, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control ' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= f.submit 'Добавить', class: 'btn btn-success btn-secondary' %>
      </span>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <br>
  <table id="tasks" class="table table-striped">

    <%= render @tasks %>

  </table>
</div>
```

**Контроллер:**

```
def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{}
    end
  end
```

**Дополнение:**

Создал *partial* для редактирования *tasks/_edit_task.hrml.erb* , в нем создал форму:

```
<%= form_for(@task, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control ' %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= f.submit 'Добавить', class: 'btn btn-success btn-secondary' %>
      </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Добавил файл** *edit.js.erb*:

```
$('#row_<%= @task.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render("edit_task") %>');
```

Но не получается отрисовать поле редактирования в строке таблицы:
[image: Отображение таблицы]

Comment: Для того чтобы редактировать запись, нужна форма, которая рисуется екшеном edit. Затем данные с формы отправляются АЯКСом в экшн update. Для того чтобы отправить аяксом форму, нужно передать в хелпер её рисующий параметр :remote, со значением true.

Comment: Спасибо! С этим разобрался почти сразу, но проблема в том, что у меня поле для редактирования заменяет строку в самой таблице. А нужно, что бы на месте где отображается **task.name** было поле для редактирования. Я дополню свой вопрос.

Comment: В таком случае вам придется освоить какой-нибудь клиентский фреймворк.

Comment: А при помощи JQuery нормально реализовать на ваш взгляд это как то можно?

Comment: Есть какой-то плагин, https://plugins.jquery.com/editable/ , вроде. Но это всё будет выглядеть костылем.